# avahi-resolve works but mdns

Tags: avahi, nsswitch, mdns

I have an updated Debian 11 (bullseye) setup and want to use avahi to connect to locally connected computers.

avahi works, for example:

```
avahi-resolve -n4 prag11mono.local
```

gives `prag11mono.local 10.0.0.105` which is correct. However, `ping` (or `ssh`) for the same host

```
ping prag11mono.local
PING prag11mono.local.rpz.GS.local (127.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
```

Here I do not understand where the `rpz.GS.local` addition comes from. It is not added to `ssh prag11mono.local`, but the request goes to `127.0.0.2` as well.

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I have

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

but
getent hosts bhutan.local

returns nothing. I have no `/etc/mdns.allow` file.

The connection between `avahi-daeomon` and `mdns4` is puzzling. I can restart avahi-daemon with systemctl; But how do I restart `mdns`?

I fear that I am missing some installation. I tried to install the package `nss-mdns` but got `unable to locate package` -- it should be available for bullseye. I installed `libnss-mdns` and checked that the required files are in `/lib/libnss_mdns*

What is missing? How to debug?

Comment: It looks like your resolver might be configured to use Response Policy Zones (RPZs). See for example [Set Up Response Policy Zone (RPZ) in BIND Resolver on CentOS/RHEL](https://www.linuxbabe.com/redhat/response-policy-zone-rpz-bind-centos)

Comment: thank you for the hint. unfortunately, I could not see any trace of rpz installed (or any conf fille).

Answer (score 0):

with much confusion of what applies to the current debian 11 (bullseye) solution. I found that I had not installed `bind9` (but just the related specific packages) and needed to

```
systemctl enable named-resolvconf
```

I guess the defaults for `nsswitch.conf` was ok. with `named-resolvconf` running. `dig` did not return any hint to `rpz` as before. However, I need not run

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
systemctl status systemd-resolved
```

which return both `disabled; inactive`. I saw some hints these might be necessary, but likely with another configuration.

It is perhaps important to differentiate between `resolvconf` and `systemd-resolved` which do somewhat similar things, but are not compatible. My solution seems to be relying on `resolvconf` and `bind9`.

Answer (score 0):

I was banging on the same problem with recent Debian kernel (Raspberry Pi OS). After reading through nss-mdns documentation and numerous instructions on the internet, I tried both `mdns` and `mdns_minimal` and their combinations, all to the same result that had ping never working.

Then I dug in with `strace ping ...` trying to see how far it gets into `libnss-mdns` and/or `avahi-daemon`, and discovered that both options `mdns` and `mdns_minimal` are trying to read `/etc/mdns.allow` file, and if it is not found, give up, contrary to multiple places claiming that if the file does not exist they consider the default as if it was present with "*" - BIG FALSEHOOD!

So I added the missing `/etc/mdns.allow` file:

```
# /etc/mdns.allow
.local.
.local
```

and lo and behold - it started to work.

Comment: Interesting observation. I am now using Debian 12 (bookworm) and use the Raspberry Debian package (https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/). Perhaps is there a connection?